# Debugging VS Code extension stuck in "Building..."

Tags: vscode-debugger

I followed [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension#debugging-the-extension) to build my first VS Code extension. But after I pressed F5, the Extension Development Host window didn't show as expected. Only "Building..." appeared in the status bar and never finished. This issue happens when all extensions are disabled.

[Here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/112534) is a similar issue. That issue can be fixed by removing `"terminal.integrated.inheritEnv": false,`. In my `settings.json`, there are two lines similar to this:

```json
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Git Bash",
"terminal.integrated.enableMultiLinePasteWarning": false,
```

I removed them, and the window showed! But I don't know why.